# How many ommatidia does a honeybee have?

Tags: neuroscience, entomology, vision, eyes

European honeybees (Apis mellifera) have compound eyes made of tiny facets called ommatidia. The number of ommatidia is usually known in most model insects, but I cannot find reference for the European honeybees, despite bees being highly studied. How many ommatidia does a European honeybee have on average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4700 - 5400, according to [Somanathan *et al*. (2009)](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/jexbio/212/15/2448.full.pdf). They base their reported values on two other papers.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Somanathan *et al*., *J Exp Biol* (2009); **212**: 2448-53](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/jexbio/212/15/2448.full.pdf)</sub>